# Validate functions before inserting then into functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I'd like to know if the functions below follow best practices in terms of ensuring the best performance and security before deploying to the main site.

**1. Remove paged category description**

```
add_action( 'wp', 'tu_remove_paged_category_description' );
function tu_remove_paged_category_description() {
    $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if ( 1 !== $page ) {
        remove_action( 'generate_archive_title', 'generate_archive_title' );
        add_action( 'generate_archive_title', 'tu_custom_paged_archive_title' );
    }
}

function tu_custom_paged_archive_title() {
    ?>
    <header class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title">
            <?php the_archive_title(); ?>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <?php
}
```

**2. Allow HTML editing of author biography**

```
remove_filter('pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_kses');  
add_filter( 'pre_user_description', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
```

**3. Limit number of posts on first page of selected categories**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! is_paged() && is_category(array (2 , 3) )) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
    }
} );
```

**4. prevent the category widget from using the category description as the list item title attribute**

```
function mbf_disable_cat_desc_widget_list_titles ( $cat_args ) {
    $cat_args[ 'use_desc_for_title' ] = 0;
    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'mbf_disable_cat_desc_widget_list_titles' );
```

**5. Create shortcode by listing subcategories belonging to that category**

```
function mbf_subcategories($atts, $content = null ){extract(shortcode_atts(array('count'=>'10','show_count' =>0,'hide_empty'=>0), $atts));
$parents = array();
if(is_category())   { //If on a Category Archive Page, show its subcategories, if any
        $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'), false);
        $id = ($cat->category_parent==0)? $cat->cat_ID : $cat->category_parent; 
        if (get_term_children($id, 'category') != "") {
        //List of subcategories with parent category in title.
            $args =( array('show_option_none'=>'','title_li' => '','echo'=>0,'show_count'=> $show_count,'number' => $count,'hide_empty'=>$hide_empty,'child_of'=>$id)); 
            $output = '<ol>'.wp_list_categories($args).'</ol>'; 
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('mbf_subcategories', 'mbf_subcategories');
```